# Нужно вывести параметры изображения (высоту и ширину), но у меня пишет что модуля нет: No module named 'Image'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pil, python-import, pillow

```
import Image
image_path = '/game/pathon/24.jpg'
img = Image.open(image_path)
width,height = img.size
print(width,height)
```

Comment: Если модуля нет - попробуйте его поставить

Comment: Если возникла ошибка, при решении какой-либо (возможно большой) задачи, то следует конкретный вопрос именно об ошибке спрашивать (опционально упомянув охватывающую задачу)—добавьте в заголовок что-нибудь вроде `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'`. Если вы спросите про "как импортировать модуль Image", то это вопрос может быть полезен не только людям, которые хотят получить "высоту и ширину изображения", но и всем кто имеет сложности с импортированием Image модуля.

Comment: пишет что No module named 'Image' , я так понял нужно скачать библиотеку Pil

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы импортировать `Image` модуль, вам необходимо [поставить pillow пакет](https://python-pillow.org/):

```
$ pip install pillow
```

Comment: это прямо в коде прописывать?

Comment: @agre если вы не знаете «что такое `pip install`  и что означают слова *"поставить Питон пакет"»* то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос (можете всю фразу внутри «» в виде заголовка вопроса использовать).